# Problem accessing Eclipse source through proxy.eclipse.org

Tags: eclipse, open-source, cvs, tortoisecvs

I'm trying to access the eclipse source code in cvs, but unfortunately, the location I'm at blocks all non-standard tcp/ip ports.  I spoke with a sysadmin on the phone, and he recommended that I try to find a way to download the source using the port 80 or port 443 proxy listed at: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto#CVS_and_firewalls

The problem I'm having is that neither of the sites (proxy.eclipse.org:80 and pebbles.eclipse.org:443) do not seem to be available to connect to using either the CVS in eclipse or tortoiseCVS.  I've been trying to connect using the following setup:

```
Host: proxy.eclipse.org
Repository Path: /cvsroot/eclipse
User: Anonymous
Pass: <blank>
Connection Type: pserver
Use Port: 80
```

I've also tried:

```
Host: pebbles.eclipse.org
Repository Path: /cvsroot/eclipse
User: Anonymous
Pass: <blank>
Connection Type: pserver
Use Port: 443
```

Both of these give me the following exception when I try to fetch the module list:
Could not connect to:

I/O exception occurred: No response from server.

Thoughts on this?  Perhaps there is a newer server to download the source that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try contacting webmaster@eclipse.org.

Comment: Ah, yes... actually, believe it or not, this didn't occur to me to try.  ;)  I feel foolish.  I'll try that, thank you.